# How do I configure a WinRM jump host for use with Ansible?

Tags: windows, deployment, ansible, continuous-integration

How do I configure a jump host to access Windows servers that I have no direct access to?

The Ansible documentation [explains how to do this for Linux](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to) but doesn't mention how to achieve something similar when using WinRM against Windows servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send winrm traffic thru a proxy such as nginx since it's just basic https traffic. If you set up a rule per "target node" in your nginx config so that each node gets a unique url (proxy.domain.com/node1, proxy.domain.com/node2 etc) and each node points to real.fqdn.com/wsman) you will be able to proxy multiple winrm connections thru one jump host. This was discussed in the following PR:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/12054